# JQuery Datatable Responsiveness Issue with Fixed Column

Tags: javascript, datatables

When I use fixed column in JQuery Datatable it doesn't work properly if I resize the window.

If I remove scrollX from options, it appears just fine however fixedColumn feature doesn't work then.

See my options below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        300,
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   true,

    } );
} );
```

[Link To Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neqqn3o6/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `width="100%"` in your table tag.

It should be working by doing this.

Comment: I think I found out the answer. just add `width="100%"` in your table tag it should be working by doing this

Comment: It works like a charm :) Update your comment , so I can accept your solution.